# replace THIS (sentence) with THAT within several articles via SQL / PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have added a signature to hundreds of articles using this sql code :

```
UPDATE xxx_content 
SET introtext = CONCAT(introtext, '<br/>signature blabla<br/>') 
WHERE catid IN (778, 779, 780);
```

I would like to know if there is a way to use the same function as "find THIS and replace with THAT" as to update my signature frequently.

P.S: a trick that would work anywhere in the content (not only at the bottom) would be more than perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use something like this:

```
UPDATE xxx_content 
SET introtext = replace(introtext, 'THIS', 'THAT')
WHERE catid IN (778, 779, 780) and introtext like '%THIS%'
```

Comment: Just one thing, it's a good idea to SELECT REPLACE(something, 'THIS', 'THAT') to check your SQL before running an update, especially if you use PHP where the arguments are another way round

Comment: Great! Thanks so much Fthiella! It's working like a charm! Thanks for the trick popnoodles!